# How to target HTML that is side-loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments, checkout

I am working with a payment gateway called Stripe, using specifically its [checkout cart](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) system.

I have managed to get the cart working, it creates customers, orders and payments as and when I need depending on the product. However, I am not very javascript oriented but want to integrate a way of automatically inserting a users email into the checkout email field. I have tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.stripe-button-el').click(function() {
        setTimeout(function() { 
            $('.Fieldset').closest('.Fieldset-input').attr('value', 'some@email.com');
            console.log('Value 1: ' + $('.Fieldset-input').attr('value'));
            console.log('Value 2: ' + $('.Fieldset').closest('.Fieldset-input') .attr('value'));
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

However, both values are undefined. The reason I added the `setTimeout()` is because the checkout is triggered by a button, the HTML is not added to the site until that button is clicked, therefore, I do not have access to its properties. I know this is done for security to prevent you accessing the card information but is there any way around this?

I have the users email stored in an object, so I just want to say do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var user { 'email': <?= $email ?> };

    // put this email inside the checkout email property
    $('input[type=email]').attr('value', user.email);
}
```

Comment: Check the optional configuration options [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom)

Comment: @Liam doesn't seem to be. could be some form submission stuff.

Comment: *the HTML is not added to the site until that button is clicked* if it's dynamically loaded use `.on()`

Comment: It is a form that gets added of which the ID on the input field is unique (changes each time) so its hard to target like that, I'm looking for a way to do it with Stripe configuration @Liam

Comment: Did you consider that they do this for a good reason? I.e. to prevent XSS attacks?

Comment: Yes but how does anything you're saying answer the question? If anything, yomisimie has answered it @Liam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that it is adding elements on a postback, so in my opinion you have to have a check in the doc ready block to see if the element exist. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.Fieldset').find('.Fieldset-input').is(':visible')) {
    $('.Fieldset').find('.Fieldset-input').attr('value', 'some@email.com');
    console.log('Value 1: ' + $('.Fieldset-input').attr('value'));
    console.log('Value 2: ' + $('.Fieldset').find('.Fieldset-input').attr('value'));
  }
});
```

and seems to me you have to use `.find()` method to get the `input` instead.

Comment: I will definitely try this on other fields like the background css etc because that is not customizable ;) thank-you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @yomisimie for supplying this in the comments, there is an 'advanced' way of adding the button which contains an 'email' field:

```
handler.open({
    email: 'some@email.com'
});
```

Which rightfully can be found in the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom).